# How to remove separator on hover in horizontal css navigation?

Tags: css, navigation, separator

I have a css navigation with a separator between the menu items. When I hover over one item that contains a submenu (eg. "Lifestyle") then those separators look very ugly, because they are not "within" the link background area, but extend to the left and right. 
Is there a way to remove those separators, only on hover and active class?

Here is my css code:

```
    #mainnav {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 26px;
    float: right;
    right:0;
    z-index:100;
}
#mainnav ul,
#mainnav li,
#mainnav span,
#mainnav a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#mainnav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#mainnav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #AEB67F;
}
#mainnav ul li a {
    padding: 50px 12px 57px 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainnav ul li a:hover, #mainnav ul li a.active  {
    background-color: #AEB67F;
    padding: 50px 12px 57px 12px;
}
#mainnav > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#mainnav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
#mainnav ul li {
    border-left:solid 1px #B4BC84;
}
#mainnav ul li:last-child {
    border:none;
}
#mainnav ul ul li + li:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
}
#mainnav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#mainnav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#mainnav ul ul {
    background: rgb(174,182,127); 
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 74px;
    width:170px;
}
#mainnav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #94A062;
    border-top: none;
}
#mainnav ul ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 8px 30px 8px 12px;
}
#mainnav ul ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#mainnav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(48,50,40);
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
     -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
     -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
     -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
     padding: 8px 30px 8px 18px;
}
#mainnav ul ul li:hover {
    background: rgb(48,50,40);
    padding: 8px 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Here is a link to the site I am working on:
http://prestigetrips.com/lapointe/index.php?id=1

I hope you can help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `border-left:solid 1px #B4BC84;` line from `#mainnav ul li {` .

I hope this will help you!

Comment: This removed the separator completely :( But the solution from Barnee worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a short script like

```
$('.menu1').mouseenter(function{
    $(this).css('border-left', '0');
}).mouseleave(function{
    $(this).css('border-left', 'add your values here');
});
```

This is one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around and came up with this:

Change `#mainnav ul li` from `border-left` to `border-right`,
and

```
#mainnav ul li:last-child {
   border: medium none;
}
```

to:

```
#mainnav ul li:first-child {
   border: medium none;
}
```

Now add the folowing style:

```
#mainnav ul li:hover,
#mainnav ul li:hover + li {
   border: none;
}
```

It's called the [Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).
It should work in IE8 and up.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works! The only problem now is a "1px jump" when I hover. I already tried to adjust, but nothing works. Can you help here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I had to add

```
#mainnav ul li:first-child:hover{
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Now there is no more "1px jump", and it looks fine. Thank you all for your help!